# ¿Puedo usar un valor de una clase en CSS en otra?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una clase que tiene la propiedad `height` en `auto` y tengo otra clase que quiero que tenga el mismo valor. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer eso?

```
.texto {
  height: auto;
}

.imagenes {
  height: ("que pongo aca");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes colocar 2 clases separadas por coma

```
.texto,.imagenes {
  height: auto;
}
```

Puedes crear una variable global

```
:root{
  --altura: auto;
}
.texto {
   height: var(--altura);
}
.imagenes {
   height: var(--altura);
}
```

Y si en tu estructura, por algún motivo, `texto` es siempre padre de `imagen`, puedes heredar

```
<div class="texto">
   <div class="imagen"></div>
</div>
```

```
.texto {
  height: auto;
}

.imagenes {
  height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: El problema que tengo es que mi div imágenes height en auto es más pequeña que mi div texto, y yo quiero que ambas sean iguales teniendo el tamaña de texto. Hay alguna forma?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de variables en CSS. La ventaja de esto es que puedes reutilizar y actualizar fácilmente el valor de las propiedades que lo utilicen, de la cual es una forma de estructurar tu CSS mucho más legible y entendible.

---

Revisando la [**documentación**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), para inicializar las variables y comenzar a reutilizarlas, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
:root {
  --mivariable: auto;
}
```

El valor de `--mivariable` es `auto`, de la cual, ese valor lo puedo reutilizar en distintas propiedades, de la siguiente forma:

```
.texto {
  height: var(--mivariable);
}

.imagenes {
  height: var(--mivariable);
}
```

Aquí, tus dos clases toman el mismo valor en su propiedad `height`, en donde el valor sería el `auto`, y si yo cambio el valor de `--mivariable: auto;`, el cambio afecta para las dos clases.